# How do I eliminate extra line in Python multi-line string?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, string, double-quotes

I made a HTML Basic Markup string in Python and I made the string split over multiple lines, however, I ran into a problem. This is an HTML Basic Markup string and I want to to appear like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So I created a string in python and this is what it looks like:

```
HTML_Basic_Markup = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    
</body>
</html>
"""
```

When I print HTML_Basic_Markup I get an extra space at the top, so to fix this I did this:

```
HTML_Basic_Markup = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    
</body>
</html>
"""
```

However, I want to make the code look neat and want the Doctype to be aligned with the rest of the code, so how would I remove the line which is created at the top?

Comment: If you want `<!DOCTYPE html>`  to be at the start of the line in order to be aligned with rest of the tags, the triple quotes should be on previous line, thus introducing the extra blank line you want to avoid. If `"""<!DOCTYPE html>`  is at the start - it will not be aligned. I don't see the need to make the code more neat than it is now. Of course you can always have the `html` in separate file or strip the extra line afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String objects support a `strip` method you can use to remove leading and trailing characters (including newlines). [See here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).